# Add class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `jquery 3.3.1` to create a html element, like the following:

```js
var $elem = $('<span>', {
  'data-function': "addSynonym",
  'data-id': 1,
  'data-options': '[test1, test2, test3]',
  'data-all': '[test0, test-1, test-2]',
  'html': $('<span>', {
    'text': "test"
  })
});

console.log($elem[0]);
console.log($elem[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to add the bootstrap class `class="badge badge-info"` to my two `span` elements.

Any suggestions how to add this directly via jquery?

Comment: Did you try to add the `class` key with a value to that object?  Are you aware of the `addClass()` method, as a second option?

Comment: Just add `'class': 'badge badge-info'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just the class same as you did for the `data attributes` for also you can use [addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```js
var $elem = $('<span>', {
  'data-function': "addSynonym",
  'data-id': 1,
  'data-options': '[test1, test2, test3]',
  'class': 'badge badge-info',
  'data-all': '[test0, test-1, test-2]',
  'html': $('<span>', {
    'text': "test",
    'class': 'badge badge-info'
  })
});

console.log($elem[0]);
console.log($elem[0].innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```